# Case cannot fall through from one case label to another

Tags: winforms, switch-statement, case

Hi for some reason the break at the end of the "AndGroup" case is unreachable. I have tried to fix this with a goto and even moving the "return true" without result. Can anyone help me out?

```
switch (dependant[0])
{
        case "AndGroup": 
             string[] sAndItems = 
                 dependant[10].Split(
                      new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            foreach (string sAndItem in sAndItems)
            {
                if (SC_Product.Dependancies.ContainsKey(sAndItem))
                {
                    if (!SC_Product.Dependancies[sAndItem].DependantInstalled)
                        return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
            break;

        case "Windows":
```

Comment: can we have the whole block of code, is it a method or what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `break` is unreachable because you have already exited via `return true` - there's no possible code branch by which the `break` can be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Stuart is right "there's no possible code branch by which the break can be executed" , you may set a field but don't use return.

Comment: I forgot to add a break; statement to the windows case. Adding the break; and returning the bool value by means of a variable seemed to fix the problem! Thank you for your input.